# Visual Studio 2019 build errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-project

I have API project (.NET Framework 4.6) that contains a lot of different controllers, nuget packages, swagger, EF etc.
If i load this project & make a build - everything succeeded (No issue found) and i can deploy my project to DevOps. However if i add atliest one line of code & make a build i get more that 6000 errors.
I already tried to clean & rebuild my project but this does not help.

[image]

Some of those 6000 exeptions:

- Consider merging the types defined in 'WebsiteApi' with another namespace.
- Because the behavior of 'string.Format(string, object, object, object)' could vary based on the current user's locale settings, replace this call in 'CampusController.GetExternal()' with a call to 'string.Format(IFormatProvider, string, params object[])'. If the result of 'string.Format(IFormatProvider, string, params object[])' will be displayed to the user, specify 'CultureInfo.CurrentCulture' as the 'IFormatProvider' parameter. Otherwise, if the result will be stored and accessed by software, such as when it is persisted to disk or to a database, specify 'CultureInfo.InvariantCulture'.
- In member 'Controller.GetItems(DateTime, bool)', correct the casing of 'B' in parameter name 'B2B' by changing it to 'b'.
- Modify 'CompanyController.GetCompany(Guid)' to catch a more specific exception than 'Exception' or rethrow the exception.

My workaround is: add code -> make build -> build will not succeded -> save project -> close VS -> open project again -> build = build succeeded.

Comment: This is usually caused by outdated binaries in the `obj` and `bin` folders. Try closing Visual Studio, removing those and restarting VS. ReSharper also likes to do this, if you use that, clear its cache and try again.

Comment: All of the things you've listed are analyzer warnings: they sound like they're from FxCop. Those shouldn't be causing the build to fail. Given that you can get it to build after a bit, I think there's a separate build error hiding in the noise. We need to see what that is: it's probably easiest to search for it in the Output window

Comment: Filter the error list into only errors not warnings

Comment: You should make sure that the StyleCop/FxCop rules are properly set up for your project. Otherwise you'll get lots of these errors.

Comment: @Charlieface That won't help if "Consider Warnings as Errors" is enabled.

Comment: Removing obj and bin did not help. No ReSharper in this project. Those are all errors (not warnings)

Comment: @RandyMarsh You've probably configured warnings as errors -- I recommend disabling that just temporarily so you can see what you *actual* build-failing error(s) are. Also post the content of the Output window after doing a build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update from VS 16.8.3 to VS 16.9.0 solved this issue.

For some reason VS 16.8.3 treat [CA warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/code-quality/globalization-warnings?view=vs-2015) as errors even if its set Properties > Build > Treat warnings and errors = None"

[Discussion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1167509/code-analysis-warnings-are-treated-as-errors.html)

Comment: you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.